# How to test variable assignment in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

```
def hide_gridlines(sheet, hide_gridlines)
  sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines = false if hide_gridlines
 end
```

I need to test this method in RSpec / Ruby, and I want to write two tests, one to see if this code `sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines = false` executes if hide_gridlines is true.

The other is to ensure that code `sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines = false` does not run if hide_gridlines is false.

sheet is a worksheet that comes from the Axlsx Gem, and I created a double, but I'm not sure how to setup the double to have a sheet_view, and then test the variable declaration.

Any pointers on how to test this in RSpec, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to refactor this code? You might find that testing comes easier when this method is simplified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
context 'set sheet.sheet_view.show_grid_lines to' do
  let(:sheet_view) { double }
  let(:sheet) { double(sheet_view: sheet_view) }

  specify 'false if hide_gridlines' do
    expect(sheet_view).to receive(:show_grid_lines=).with(false)
    subject.hide_gridlines(sheet, true)
  end

  specify 'true unless hide_gridlines' do
    expect(sheet_view).not_to receive(:show_grid_lines=)
    subject.hide_gridlines(sheet, false)
  end
end
```